# Redis schema design - how to store sliding window of sensor data stream?

Tags: database-design, redis, hashset

this is my first schema design of sensor data streams, whose N-past readouts should be queryable from redis clients (<10).

1. When to hold data client-side in circular buffer rather than querying? Since some sensors have 100Hz others 1x a week, client-side is not an option for slow sensors, use mixed design local/remote which might introduce complexity?
2. Basically it boils down to *serialize a lot* or *query a lot*, two patterns i noticed during this first draft:
   [image]

   It starts with a sorted set to quickly sift by timestamp, then either the value is a stringified object (eg. 5x attributes id/temp/humid..) or place the object into an external hashset referenced by a unique value to retrieve the hashset in a second query.
   The workflow in option one on the left results into big de/serialization object but one query while the latter results in numerous querys but less payload since finegrained access. When would you use what, am i missing patterns?
3. Reading about [Cap'n Proto, FlatBuffers, and SBE](https://capnproto.org/news/2014-06-17-capnproto-flatbuffers-sbe.html)(messagepack, avro, protobuff) and ability to access field specifics with random access, the *less topics bigger stringified objects* seems to be favorable? Storage size is important since my droplet has only 1gb ram running debian. Also important to respect tcp packet size which should be ok with 500char stringified objects

   > size of the data is kept under the ethernet packet size (about 1500
   >   bytes). Actually, processing 10 bytes, 100 bytes, or 1000 bytes
   >   queries almost result in the same throughput. See the graph below. [how fast is redis blog](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)

Also blog posts/pointers with condensed knowledge of that matter is great.

[image]

Comment: note that ' Cap'n Proto, FlatBuffers, and SB' compares C++ implementations of these protocols. Libraries for other languages may differ.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [LPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/lpush), [LTRIM](https://redis.io/commands/ltrim) to make a sliding window of data for each sensor. Objects are serialized. If you'll use fast serialization method with predefined precompiled schema (colfer, protobuf, cap'n'proto) it will be blazing fast.

On the grand scheme of things you may use message queue system that will push sensor data to Redis for sliding window and to time series DB for historical data and analytics (and potentially to some backend for real-time analysis).

Comment: i do like the directio of sliding window and historical analytics, could you please extend on this, i am new to design patterns. Like fast lane for sliding window and sow lane for historcial data also in redis?

Comment: As I said, for historical data I'd suggest a special analytical DB like ClickHouse or InfluxDB. If you would store it in Redis, your memory usage would grow uncontrollably.

Comment: @ItsmeJulian regarding p3 that you added - keep logically related data in one object, but not more. with sliding windows some windows may slide faster than others, so if you try `find biggest temperature in topic 'device1:temp' and get corresponding humidity from topic 'device1:hum'`, you will get wrong data.